# how to make a clickable toast in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Can I create something similar to Toasts in Flutter ?that that appear after an event and clickable toast

example of what i want :

[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

here is an example from the docs,

```
class SnackBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SnackBar Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('SnackBar Demo'),
        ),
        body: SnackBarPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SnackBarPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(
            content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
            action: SnackBarAction(
              label: 'Undo',
              onPressed: () {
                // Some code to undo the change.
              },
            ),
          );

          // Find the Scaffold in the widget tree and use
          // it to show a SnackBar.
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        },
        child: Text('Show SnackBar'),
      ),
    )
  }
}
```

also i would recommend using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar) as it has more customization and you don't have to worry about the scaffold context.